# Using release candidate of android library security-crypto in production code

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, encrypted-shared-preference

For one of the Android projects there is a need to store some values in Shared Preferences. For that I am planning to use [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences.html)

But when I checked, one of the library [androidx.security:security-crypto](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security) on which this functionallity is dependent on is still not oficially released. Only release candidate version (1.0.0-rc03) is available

My question is - Is it fine to use this in production code? What are the chances that google might depriciate this library?

Comment: _"What are the chances that google might depriciate this library?"_ Obviously we can't know that.

Comment: @Michael, Just wanted to know is it a common practise in android world to use release candidate in production code? I am new to Android thats why asking this

Answer (score 1):

Is it a common practice to use a release candidate version in production code? Yes, unfortunately. Is it a recommended practice? Of course not. But sometimes you don't have the choice, it's still better than trying to do encryption yourself.

In my opinion Google deprecating the library completely is very unlikely. And Android being open-source, at worst you can always [copy the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/security/crypto/src/main/java/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F&autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F) yourself in your project. This isn't the problem I would worry about, I would be more concerned about using a non-stable version of a cryptography library. But as I said, it may still be better than trying to do it yourself if there aren't any viable alternatives.